Springboot 3 opentelemetry context is empty
I am able to work with springboot telemetry using micrometer and the below settings:
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'

And application.yaml:
opentelemetry:
tracing:
sampling-rate: 1  # 100% of traces
traces:
exporter: otlp
exporter:
otlp:
endpoint: "http://jaeger-collector:4317"
protocol: grpc
All this is working perfectly fine for one of the services but one of the other services, the traces/spans are sent but are not tied together. I do see the spans but not together. When i try to log the OTEL context it is empty. Not sure why this happens. Any idea? Thank you in advance!
